# How can I identify the N columns with the largest values for each row?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

My data looks something like this:

```
set.seed(122217)
df <- data.frame(ID = paste0("id",1:100), A = rnorm(100), E = rnorm(100), I = rnorm(100), O = rnorm(100), U = rnorm(100))
```

I want to produce a new data frame with 100 rows and 1+3 columns. Each row should correspond to each ID from df, the first column would be `ID`, and the others would be First, Second, Third.

I can do this with some very ugly code:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
# transpose
t_df <- transpose(df[,2:6])
# get row and colnames in order
colnames(t_df) <- df[,1]
rownames(t_df) <- colnames(df[,2:6])
id_largest <-function(data, col){
  values <- data[,col]
  names(values) <- row.names(data)
  values <- sort(values, decreasing = T)
  ranking <- names(values)
  out <- data.frame( id= colnames(data)[col], First=ranking[1], Second=ranking[2], Third=ranking[3])
  return(out)
}

ranking <- purrr::map(1:ncol(t_df), id_largest, data=t_df) %>% rbindlist()
```

This code produces what I want:

```
> head(ranking)
id First Second Third
1: id1     A      E     I
2: id2     U      O     I
3: id3     A      E     I
4: id4     E      U     I
5: id5     I      A     U
6: id6     I      A     U
```

But is not very elegant. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: @arkun nope. I added an example to better explain what I want.

Comment: Could you please run the code on your end?  I get errors.  Is it the `transpose` from `data.table` or `purrr`?

Comment: The code runs fine on both my linux and windows computers. Transpose is from `data.table`

Comment: For me, `t(apply(df[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) names(x)[order(-x)][1:3]))` is compact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

melt(setDT(df), id = 1)[order(-value)
                        ][, variable[1:3], ID
                          ][, dcast(.SD, ID ~ rowid(ID, prefix = 'p'))]
```

which gives:

> ```
>         ID p1 p2 p3
>   1: id001  A  E  I
>   2: id002  U  O  I
>   3: id003  A  E  I
>   4: id004  E  U  I
>   5: id005  I  A  U
> ....
>  95: id095  O  A  U
>  96: id096  U  A  I
>  97: id097  A  U  O
>  98: id098  U  A  O
>  99: id099  I  E  U
> 100: id100  E  I  U
> ```

The same logic implemented with the `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(key, value, -1) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(ID, -value) %>% 
  slice(1:3) %>% 
  select(-value) %>% 
  mutate(rn = paste0('p', row_number())) %>% 
  spread(rn, key)
```

---

Used data:

```
set.seed(122217)
df <- data.frame(ID = sprintf("id%03d",1:100), A = rnorm(100), E = rnorm(100), I = rnorm(100), O = rnorm(100), U = rnorm(100))
```

Comment: I discovered rowid from this post which is ~ 10x faster than `tbl[, nS := 1:.N, id]`

Answer (score 6):

Solution using `apply`:

```
 foo <- colnames(df)[-1]
 data.frame(df[, 1], 
            t(apply(df[, -1], 1, function(x) foo[tail(order(x), 3)]))[, 3:1])
```